# Bar Chart Legend

Tags: arcgis-desktop, legend, mapping, chart

I am trying to add legend to a map with bar charts which would be meaningful. The default legend doesn't explain the size of bars on the map.

I have tried this one: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/mapping/bar-chart-legends/ but doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Can you add a few images showing the behavior you're seeing and the result you want to get instead?